# ListView empty view will not show up

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview

When I set `list.setEmptyView(empty)` the list background color is white and I **can't find a text view** with Green color, but if I comment this line the list background color will be Cyan.

addedItems array:

```
String[] addedItems = {};
```

This is `loadList` function:

```
private void loadList() {
    ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list);
    if(addedItems != null) {
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addedItems);
        list.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        TextView empty = new TextView(this);

        empty.setText("The list is empty");
        empty.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        list.setEmptyView(empty);

        list.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
}
```

This is my `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ir.vahid.actionbarmenu.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >
</ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try with xml.. put textview there and set at runtime

Comment: @NikhilBorad, I made a seprate xml for text view but not different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the empty view manually (inflated) to the "parent" view of the Listview:

```
ListView my_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
View emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_view,null);
((ViewGroup)my_list.getParent()).addView(emptyView); 
listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

OR

Your TextView should be placed right under the ListView item with its visibility set to gone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ir.vahid.actionbarmenu.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >
</ListView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/emptyList" >
</TextView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why it's working?!! I tried with separate xml file but not worked!

Comment: because you have not added it width and height in it but if you are having different layout than use my answer code it will solve your issue

Comment: @Vahid did you got it ?

Comment: you can tell me what you did not understanding i will help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162142/discussion-between-vahid-and-amit-vaghela).